# PHP Syntax Error? - Create a MultiDimentional Array, Use a foreach loop - output HTML

Tags: php, syntax, multidimensional-array, foreach

QUESTION ANSWERED:

After messing around with a few things, The combination of the comma at the and of my last array element, and not having the image source path typed correctly was the problem.

Everything works great. It never ceases to amaze me at how a simple syntax error can throw everything out of whack.

Thank you Jonathan and tmsimont! The combo of you're answers fixed my problem.

Time to get a good PHP debugger, Netbeans probably, because Dreamweaver just isn't cutting it for me and I'm not versed enough to hand code YET!

EDIT:

I'm going to try and make myself a little more clear by showing my output source:

```
<body>
<div id="main">
<div class="container">
<div class="sponsorInner">
<a href="'.$company[1].'">
<img src="img/sponsors/'.$company[0].'.png">
</a>
</div>
</div>
'; } ?&gt;
</div>
</body>
```

3 things not working:I need the first div with the class gold to render, and the $'s from the array to populate the image link and path.

ORIGINAL QUESTION:
I am trying to create multiple div arrangements on a page using a multidimentional array and a foreach loop to populate the div contents with a an image mnemonically named in a relative path folder and the image to be a hyperlink.

My output is not displaying the first  correctly, and not populating the array $'s.

This seems right to me, am I missing some type of escape or syntax?

```
    <body>

    <?php   

        $sponsor = array(
            array('Allstate','http://www.allstateagencies.com/'),
            array('Arrowhead','http://www.arrowheadwater.com/'),
        );
    ?>  

<div id="main">

    <div class="container">     

        <?php           

            foreach($sponsor as $company)
            {
                echo '
                    <div class="gold">
                        <div class="sponsorInner">
                            <a href="'.$company[1].'"><img src="img/sponsors/'.$company[0].'.png"/></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                ';
            }
        ?>


    </div><!--.container-->

</div><!--#main-->

</body>
```

Comment: And what happens? What error do you get?

Comment: try harder to describe your actual problem.

Comment: I tried making my question a little easier to understand by showing my output source code. I seriously thought this would work first try, It seems like I'm not escaping quotes. Or maybe I need to drop in and out of PHP between HTML?

Comment: What server are you using to parse/test the PHP? I copy/pasted the code from your question and it ran fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

A total guess.. since that's all I can do with the way you've phrased your question... but if your problem is with the image output, try putting a "/" in beginning the src attribute of the image:

```
  <a href="'.$company[1].'"><img src="/img/sponsors/'.$company[0].'.png"/></a>
```

that way the browser looks for the img directory from the base of the site, instead of from within whatever subdirectory you're in.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to make my question a little easier to understand by showing my output source code. I've tried using relative and absolute paths, root folders, ect. I still get the problem with my output.

Comment: Thanks again, trouble shooting the path name, I fixed an error and it helped!

Answer (score 0):

Why not do your array this way

```
$sponsor = array(
  'Allstate' => 'http://www.allstateagencies.com/',
  'Arrowhead' => 'http://www.arrowheadwater.com/'
);
```

and later

```
<?php
foreach($sponsor as $company_name => $company_site)
{
?>
  <div class="gold">
    <div class="sponsorInner">
      <a href="<?php echo $company_site ?>"><img src="img/sponsors/<?php echo $company_name ?>.png"/></a>
    </div>
  </div>
<?php
}
?>
```

**Edit**

Remember, your file name is case sensitive. So the `.png` will need capital letters in their name. You can add the `strtolower()` around `$company_name` if you need them lowercase.

Comment: I did name the png files accordingly, If I end up working with a large amount of images, I will put this to use. Cheers!

Comment: you're suggestion gave me some ideas for the future. Thanks for the response!

Answer (score -1):

You have an comma at the end of this line which you don't need:

```
array('Arrowhead','http://www.arrowheadwater.com/'),
```

Please try to do basic debugging before posting.

Comment: Even though it's not needed it's nothing that will break the code.

Comment: Awesome tip, I've seen arrays written both ways, I didn't know which was "standard". I'm an HTML whiz, but new to PHP. Thanks again.

Comment: no, unfortunately this is still my output source: (see above source code in original question)

Comment: Yes, yes this was the problem. I will look into a good de-bug program. Netbeans probably. I was trying to hand code in Notepad++ and checked syntax in Dreamweaver. No errors = me pulling my hair out over something a basic debug probably would have caught. You're a hero!